# Group with exactly two subgroups of index 2

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> I am looking for a group $G$ such that $G$ has exactly two subgroups of index 2.

I have searched by GAP but I couldn't find it.

Comment: Why are you looking for such a group?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Such a group does not exist. Suppose the group $G$ has subgroups $N \ne M$ of index two. Clearly they are both normal, and $M N = G$. Then
$$
\lvert G : M \cap N \rvert 
=
\lvert G : M \rvert 
\cdot
\lvert M : M \cap N \rvert 
=
\lvert G : M \rvert 
\cdot
\lvert M N : N \rvert 
=
\lvert G : M \rvert
\cdot 
\lvert G : N \rvert
=
4.
$$
So $G / M \cap N$ is a group of order $4$, which is isomorphic to the [Klein four-group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein_four-group) $V$, as $a^{2} \in M \cap N$ for each $a \in G$.

Since $V$ has *three* subgroups of index $2$, $G$ has at least three such subgroups, by the [correspondence theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correspondence_theorem).

Comment: many thanks, It is a tricky solution

Comment: Is this theorem or exercise?

Comment: @Babgen, it could surely be assigned as an exercise, once the main ingredients have been taught.

Comment: A similar argument shows that if $G$ has at least two different normal subgroups of index $p$ prime, then it has at least $p+1$ different normal subgroups of index $p$.

Comment: @NickyHekster, sure! Clearly for $p > 2$ one has to add explicitly the normality assumption.

Comment: Not if the prime is the smallest one dividing $|G|$ .:-))

Comment: @NickyHekster, agreed! ;-)

Comment: May I ask why $G=MN$?

Comment: @MashedPotato $M N$ is a subgroup of $G$ properly containing $M$, which has index $2$ in $G$.

Comment: Why $|M:M\cap N|=|MN:N|$?

Answer (score 1):

There is a very nice result proved by R.R. Crawford and K.D. Wallace, *On the number of subgroups of index 2 - an application of Goursat's Theorem for groups*, Math. Magazine, **48**, no. 3 (1975). Let $I_2(G)=\#\{H \lt G: |G:H|=2\}$.

**Theorem** Let $n$ be a non-negative integer. Then there exists a group $G$ with $I_2(G)=n$ if and only if $n=2^k-1$ for some non-negative integer $k$.

The theorem can be generalized as follows. Let $p$ be a prime and $N_p(G)=\#\{H \lhd G: |G:H|=p\}$.

**Theorem** Let $n$ be a non-negative integer. Then there exists a group $G$ with $N_p(G)=n$ if and only if $n=\frac{p^k-1}{p-1}$ for some non-negative integer $k$.

Answer (score -1):

$G=S_3\times S_3$ would work. The subgroups of index two being $\mathbb{Z}_3\times S_3$ and $S_3\times\mathbb{Z}_3$.

Edit: Removed last sentence due to an error pointed out by Tobias Kildetoft.

Edit: $G$ is not an example of such a group as Andreas Caranti points out.

Comment: Your last comment is not correct. Take for example $C_2\times C_2$.

Comment: Oh of course, thank you!

Comment: why  does $G$ have exactly two subgroup of index 2

Comment: @Babgen Indeed, I pointed it out as an example of why the last comment was wrong, not as an example of a group satisfying what you needed.

Comment: There is a third subgroup of order two in $G$. In fact $N = C_{3} \times C_{3}$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, and the quotient $G/N$ is isomorphic to $C_{2} \times C_{2}$, so by the correspondence theorem here there are *three* subgroups of index $2$.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti Indeed, the third one is probably most easy to describe as the set of elements $(g,h)$ with $\rm{sgn}(g) = \rm{sgn}(h)$.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft, quite right, and actually the argoment appears to extend to show that a group cannot have exactly two subgroups of index two, see my answer.