# Existence of finite Galois extensions

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

> Is there a finite Galois extension $F$ of $K$ such that there are exactly two fields $E$ such that $K\leq E \leq F$ and $[E:K]=2$?

I guess there is. I know there is no such finite Galois extension when $[F:E]=2$ (related: [Properties of Finite Galois Extensions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3535579/properties-of-finite-galois-extensions)). Does anyone have specific example?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/582313/group-with-exactly-two-subgroups-of-index-2 where it is proved that there is no finite group with exactly two subgroups of index two.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Can you explain why the fact "there is no finite group with exactly two subgroups of index two" is related to my question? Thanks.

Comment: @GerryMyerson When $[F:E]=2$, then I think showing there is no finite group with exactly two subgroups of index two works. But when $[E:K]=2$ shouldn't I need to show there is no finite group with exactly two subgroups with order two?

Comment: If $F$ is Galois over $K$, and $[E:K]=2$, then the Galois group of $F$ over $E$, which I'll write as $G(F/E)$, is a subgroup of $G(F/K)$ of index two. Exactly two fields $E$ with $[E:K]=2$ means exactly two subgroups of $G(F/K)$ of index two.

Comment: By the way, it's also true that there's no finite group with exactly two subgroups of order two. Any finite group with a subgroup of order two must have even order, and must have an odd number of elements of order two. If $x$ and $y$ both generate subgroups of order two, then there must be another element of order two, hence, another subgroup of order two.

Comment: Do you understand, Sungn?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP has abandoned it.